# do two arduinos that are linked to a common 9v rail and ground still need a common negative connection for a serial tx rx connection?

Tags: serial, arduino-mega, wires

so that there a 2 wires rather than 3 to connect between the two for purposes of serial communication.  And the same question for 3 arduino megas on a common rail and using serial connections?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All voltages are ground referenced, hence the ground is the only (supply) connection required. Remote modules can be self-powered and signals will still be discriminated as long as ground is connected.

Comment: thank you for your prompt reply , the 9v and negative rail are connected for purposes of powering the arduino boards anyway.  I should have asked Do I need an additional connection between the grounds to that provided by the power connection.

Comment: If they're using a common ground then their grounds should be already connected.